# Display the username of query results (Parse.com on iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I am currently using the query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Tom Coomer" and it is working.
However I would like to create an array of the usernames from the results.

How would I approach this?

Thanks

I am using Parse.com and Xcode to write the app.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume you're saving your query results to an array, so what you want to do is this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]

for(PFUser *user in arrayFromQuery)
{

    [array addObject:user.username];

}
```

What this does is traverse through your array and gets the username from each user and adds it to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch only the username from the Parse :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"username"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
 // objects in results will only contain the username fields
}];
```

result array contains the name of all user.

And if u want to fetch all records and then create a array of username:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
// The find succeeded.
NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d user.", objects.count);
// Do something with the found objects
for (PFUser *object in objects) 
{
   [self.usernameArray addObject:object.username];
    NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
}
} else {
// Log details of the failure
NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

}

}];
```

where usernameArray is a NSMutableArray.